# Unidirectional rpc with grpc

Tags: grpc-java

I wanted to know if it is possible to define an RPC which does not return anything, i.e, the server can the server just consume the incoming client message and does not return any response?

Comment: Server-streaming RPC that just completes (closes) without calling onNext (or sendMessage) - using Java method names here, but other languages would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can.

You can define a service which returns a message of type `google.protobuf.Empty` and then call that service asynchronously from your client. As mentioned in the comment by @uli, you still need to send a `complete()` to the client, but you can do that first thing and then do the remaining processing.